# javascript - Coffeescript & Backbone.js - TypeError: this._ensureElement is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

**.: EDIT :.**
If you are having the same problem check your variable initialization, i forgot about *new*.

I keep getting *TypeError: this._ensureElement is not a function* and got *TypeError: this._reset is not a function* once earlier but I can't really recreate the exact setup for the latter.

I have my scripts in right order:

```
<script src="js/components/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/components/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="js/components/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

My model is registered before my collection.

It's a shopping cart app.

```
#namespacing

App =
  Collection : {}
  Model : {}
  View : {}

###
MODEL
###

class ModelItem extends Backbone.Model

  #default values

  defaults:
    name : 'Product Name' 
    quantity : 0
    unit : 'kg'

  #Increase or decrease the quantity

  change_quantity : (type) ->
    qty = @get 'quantity'
    @set 'quantity', if type is 'increase' then ++qty else --qty

###
COLLECTION
###

class CollectionItems extends Backbone.Collection

  model: ModelItem

###
VIEW
###

class ViewItems extends Backbone.View

window.view = ViewItems()
window.item = ModelItem()
```

Comment: On what line is the error?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You're missing the `new` operator.

```
window.view = new ViewItems()
window.item = new ModelItem()
```

Comment: I was expecting some dumb mistake, I just didn't expect it to be that dumb.

Comment: I knew the answer right away because I have done the same thing multiple times ;)

Comment: My god I feel silly.  Thank you for saving me so much time!

Answer (score 0):

With coffee-script if you use helpers to init views you could run into following:

```
@createSubView ViewClass
   model: model
```

Coffee-script won't complain for some reason. But js output will cause problems.

Following fixes the issue

```
@createSubView ViewClass,
   model: model
```

I hope this helps.
This might be a ticket for Coffee-Script team...